# Populate Row Range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working in Excel Workbook with 36 tabs containing similar data.
Luckily most of the data is placed in the same cell number on each tab.
I have used VBA to extract data from each tab and populate my final tab called "Output"

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim currentWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
    Dim otherSheet As Worksheet

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Set currentWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set otherSheet = currentWorkbook.Worksheets("Output")

    i = 1
    For Each currentSheet In currentWorkbook.Worksheets
        otherSheet.Range("A" & i).Value = currentSheet.Range("A2").Value
        otherSheet.Range("B" & i).Value = currentSheet.Range("D20").Value
        otherSheet.Range("AG" & i).Value = currentSheet.Range("E20").Value
        otherSheet.Range("BI" & i).Value = currentSheet.Range("F20").Value
        otherSheet.Range("CN" & i).Value = currentSheet.Range("G20").Value
        otherSheet.Range("DR" & i).Value = currentSheet.Range("H20").Value

        i = i + 1
    Next currentSheet

    Set currentSheet = Nothing
    Set currentWorkbook = Nothing
```

and the data looks like this

[image: 1]

I'm trying to populate the rest of the dates, and example would be to populate range B2:AF2 with what is present in B2 already.
Can anybody advise on how I should proceed with this?

Comment: so you want c2 populated with sheet2.b2.value, d2 with sheet3.b2.value, e2 with sheet4.b2.value, etc?

Comment: @GibralterTop
I want to populate From C2:AF2 with the value present in b2 (76.1596111) so it should look like this https://imgur.com/a/TYzf5l4

Comment: Do you just want that to happen for 2nd row or all rows?

Comment: @ZacIf you can do it for the 2nd one, I can use the example to do it for the rest.

Comment: `whateverSheet.Range("C2:AF1000").FormulaR1C1= "=R[2]C2"` should do it.